# Configure multiple sites in jboss application server

Tags: java, jboss, httpd.conf

I am using a jboss application web server, and have war files deployed already and running a website . how do i configure another site using httpd.conf and jboss to run one more site in the same jboss application server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add another server *instance*, then the easiest way is to copy and rename an existing server.

For example, copy your /server/default server and rename it something.  Now you have another server which you can throw an EAR or WAR of what have you on it.

If you try to start two simultaneously, you will face issues because both servers are running on the same port.  To fix this, you can probably use -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01 to change your port value for the particular port.  ports-01 will add 100 to your port number, so 8080 becomes 8180.  Here's how you would start it from a bat file:

```
 call %JBOSS_HOME%\bin\run.bat -c %JBoss_server% -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01
```

I don't remember if there was some config needed for port binding, but it shouldn't be hard.